# Shell / awk how to pass some value across to results of another command

Tags: command-line, aws

With this command, i get list of top ips from apache access log using AWK command, because it handles the first input variable ($1) which is ip. (then it does some things like sorting, counting etc.. but that doesn't matter now) output is simply some list of ips:

```
cat /var/log/apache2/access.log | awk '{print $1}' | sort -n | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -20
```

*Output is the list of ips.*

With this command, i am able to get the host name for each of top ip:

```
cat /var/log/apache2/access.log | awk '{print $1}' | sort -n | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -20 | awk '{print "host "$2"" | "/bin/sh"}' | awk '{print $5}'
```

*Output is the list of host names.*

But question is, how do i pass the ip to output of the last '{print $5}' part? so i will have list of ip and host name? And not two various outputs / files.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you do this kind of thing using `xargs`, for example

```
awk '{print $1}' apache.log | sort -n | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -20 | 
    xargs -L1 sh -c 'host "$2" | awk -v ip="$2" "{print ip, \$5}"' sh
```

If you have GNU awk (aka `gawk`) then you could instead do the sorting internally, and pass the IPs to the `host` command [using getline from a Pipe](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Getline_002fPipe.html)

Ex.

```
gawk -v cmd='host ' '
  {c[$1]++} 
  END{
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_desc"
    for(i in c) {
      if(++n > 20) break
      cmd i | getline; close(cmd i)
      print i, $5
    }
  }
' apache.log
```

Comment: think "last" part can be 4 or 5 maybe $NF is better suited (depending if it's an ipv4 or ipv6)

Comment: @bac0n thanks, I wondered about that - but just went with the OP's choice to make it more of a direct "translation"

Comment: amazing thanks, now let me see if i can combine it multiple times.